# Comment line affecting sourcing code for function in RStudio

Tags: r, compilation

I am writing the following function in RStudio. The function works as expected when I am able to source it successfully. However, it sometimes fails to source. As written below, it fails to source. However, if I delete one of the `-`s from the end of the fourth comment block, changing `# extract elements to faut.laut.df ----` to `# extract elements to faut.laut.df ---` suddently the code sources without any issues. Interestingly, deleting this 4th `-` also removes `extract elements to faut.laut.df` from the RStudio document outline.

```
######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
# create auth_search ---------------------------------------
# create function that wil search for
# all last authors who have published
# on the search terms
######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
auth_search <- function(
    term_set,
    elmnt = NULL,
    download = T,
    max_records = 1e6
) {
    ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
    # search -> search.l --------------------------------------
    # search pubmed using web history
    # and write out results
    ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
    require(rentrez)
    require(dplyr)
    # require(data.table)
    # require(rlist)
    # require(XML)
    search.l <- entrez_search(
        db = "pubmed",
        term = term_set,
        use_history = T
    )
    saveRDS(search.l, paste0(search_name, "_search.l.RDS"))
    ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
    # summarize -> summary.l -----------------------------------
    # get summaries of search hits using
    # web history and write out results
    ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
    if (download) {
        if (search.l$count > max_records) {
            paste0(
                "greater than ",
                max_records,
                " laut records found for this name"
            )
        }
        else if (search.l$count != 0) {
            for (seq_start in seq(1, search.l$count, download_max)) {
                if (seq_start == 1) {
                    i <- 1
                    cat(paste0(
                        "cycle ", i, " of ",
                        ceiling(search.l$count / download_max), "\n"
                    ))
                    summary.l <- entrez_summary(
                        db = "pubmed",
                        web_history = search.l$web_history,
                        always_return_list = T,
                        retmax = download_max,
                        retstart = seq_start
                    )
                }
                else {
                    i <- i + 1
                    cat(paste0(
                        "cycle ", i, " of ",
                        ceiling(search.l$count / download_max), "\n"
                    ))
                    summary.l <- append(
                        summary.l,
                        entrez_summary(
                            db = "pubmed",
                            web_history = search.l$web_history,
                            always_return_list = T,
                            retmax = download_max,
                            retstart = seq_start
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            class(summary.l) <- c("esummary_list", "list")
            rm(seq_start, i)
            saveRDS(summary.l, paste0(search_name, "_summary.rds"))
            ######################################## #
            # extract elements to faut.laut.df ----
            # extract desired information from
            # esummary, convert to dataframe
            ######################################## #
            faut.laut.l <- extract_from_esummary(
                esummaries = summary.l,
                elements = elmnt,
                simplify = F
            )
            faut.laut.df <- rbindlist(faut.laut.l)
            faut.laut.df
        }
        else {
            out <- "no last author publications"
            out
        }
    }
    else {
        search.l
    }
}
```

This is what the console shows when compiling fails:

```
> ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
> # create auth_search ---------------------------------------
> # create function that wil search for
> # all last authors who have published
> # on the search terms
> ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
> auth_search <- function(
+     term_set,
+     elmnt = NULL,
+     download = T,
+     max_records = 1e6
+ ) {
+     ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
+     # search -> search.l --------------------------------------
+     # search pubmed using web history
+     # and write out results
+     ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
+     require(rentrez)
+     require(dplyr)
+     # require(data.table)
+     # require(rlist)
+     # require(XML)
+     search.l <- entrez_search(
+       db = "pubmed",
+       term = term_set,
+       use_history = T
+     )
+     saveRDS(search.l, paste0(search_name, "_search.l.RDS"))
+     ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
+     # summarize -> summary.l -----------------------------------
+     # get summaries of search hits using
+     # web history and write out results
+     ######################################## # # # # # # # # # #
+     if (download) {
+         if (search.l$count > max_records) {
+             paste0(
+                 "greater than ",
+                 max_records,
+                 " laut records found for this name"
+             )
+         }
+         else if (search.l$count != 0) {
+             for (seq_start in seq(1, search.l$count, download_max)) {
+                 if (seq_start == 1) {
+                     i <- 1
+                     cat(paste0(
+                         "cycle ", i, " of ",
+                         ceiling(search.l$count / download_max), "\n"
+                     ))
+                     summary.l <- entrez_summary(
+                         db = "pubmed",
+                         web_history = search.l$web_history,
+                         always_return_list = T,
+                         retmax = download_max,
+                         retstart = seq_start
+                     )
+                 }
+                 else {
+                     i <- i + 1
+                     cat(paste0(
+                         "cycle ", i, " of ",
+                         ceiling(search.l$count / download_max), "\n"
+                     ))
+                     summary.l <- append(
+                         summary.l,
+                         entrez_summary(
+                             db = "pubmed",
+                             web_history = search.l$web_history,
+                             always_return_list = T,
+                             retmax = download_max,
+                             retstart = seq_start
+                         )
+                     )
+                 }
+             }
+             class(summary.l) <- c("esummary_list", "list")
+             rm(seq_start, i)
+             saveRDS(summary.l, paste0(search_name, "_summary.rds"))
+             ######################################## #
+             # extract elements to faut.laut.df ----
+             # extract desired information from
+             # esummary, convert to dataframe
+             ######################################## #
+             faut.laut.l <- extract_from_esummary(
+                 esummaries = summary.l,
+                 elements = elmnt,
+                 simplify = F
+             )
+             faut.laut.df <- rbindlist(faut.laut.l)
+             faut.laut.df
+         }
+
```

A comment line affecting the function of code seems odd to me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: ✅ also not working for me. If you look at the margin of the RStudio editor, you can see a little down-arrow on the line with the issue "----". The editor thinks "----" (exactly four dashes) makes it a segment of code that can be separated as if there were brackets.

Answer (score 0):

## Minimal issue example

```
# if you copy/paste this into RStudio, there's an arrow on the margin to
# compact the ---- as if it's in brackets like {}
f <- function() {
      # extract elements to faut.laut.df -----
}
```

I've checked it on the most recent stable RStudio download. Maybe try the dev version or else I'd suggest opening an issue on https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues with the example code I've given above.

### Update:

It's called code-folding and I guess it's a feature and not a bug: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections

Comment: thank you for finding that term, code-folding. However, the code folding isn't the problem. Your code above successfully compiles, despite the code folding, mine does not. In addition, the first 3 sections of my code that can be code-folded don't cause this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? If I use 'source', your code works for me too. If I use 'Run selected lines', it doesn't. My guess is it has to do with the place you put the comments; RStudio doesn't know how to interpret it correctly. If you click the code-folding arrow on yours, it folds all the way to the point where your code stops running.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant source, though what I've actually been doing is highlighting the appropriate text and typing Ctrl+Enter. When I copied the code to a new document in RStudio and then clicked "Source" it worked, even with 4 `-`s. And ever since I did that, highlight>Ctrl+Enter started working. I guess the problem fixed itself...